# How low is the lowest tone that a human can sing?

Tags: voice, history, choir, bass-voice

Thinking about the range of human voices and the bass voices - especially whether there has been an average of lowest tones through the past - I wonder which is the lowest tone that a human can produce?

Comment: Yes, I've found an answer, of course. I will give the point to someone who has the lowest reputation.  ;) Well, I could also pretend, that I can sing as low as 4hz that nobody can hear it! But unfortunately today we can measure it ...

Comment: Certainly the theoretical limit it 0.  Sing 4:33 that way ;-)

Comment: If I sing one note per second, am I actually singing a tone whose fundamental frequency is 1 Hz?

Comment: @ggcg - lots of folk won't get that one. You're being too Cagey.

Comment: A human - or a particular human?

Comment: * the bass voices* are  mainly *male* ;)

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably find the lowest bass voices in Russian choral music, reaching down to C1 (32.7 Hz). Such low basses are called [Oktavists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basso_profondo#Oktavist):

[The Power of the Russian Oktavist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8qu4OOQ_Dc)

Answer (score 2):

*The lowest vocal note produced by a male is G -7 (0.189 Hz) and was achieved by Tim Storms (USA) at Citywalk Studios in Branson, Missouri, USA, on 30 March 2012. Timothy is the bass singer for the vocal group 'Pierce Arrow'. The attempt was witnessed by two college music professors and an acoustician. The frequency output of Timothy's voice was measured using Bruel & Kjaer equipment (low frequency microphone, precision sound analyser and laptop for post analysis).*

https://edition.cnn.com/videos/world/2012/08/23/mclaughlin-worlds-lowest-voice.cnn

and

and this is the script of another video:

*Tim Storms has the world's deepest voice it goes solo the human ear can't hear it. Tim holds the Guinness world record for having the widest vocal range of ten octaves. my lowest note would be somewhere around it if you were to take another piano and and sit on the bottom on the left side of a piano that would be about how low I could go eight octaves lower than the lowest G on the piano. His talent was discovered after he sang at a Christian summer camp as a child and had deepened even further when he reached adulthood.*
Decca Records conducted a search along with the composer Paul Miller for a low bass voice and found Tim who sang in a low e.
on the album tranquillity with the st. Petersburg Chamber Choir

I think there is no more comment  needed!

Comment: Why the downvote?  [Tim Storms - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Storms) shows [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/score/7/2/72b23c97dt09367pu1fn80s2krk4rge/72b23c97.png) as the musical notation for G-7.

Comment: and what is the difference to my first quotation above? Did you count the ledger lines? Well, I can't count so far ;)

Comment: But does a ~0.189-Hz note even sound like a note anymore? Heck, I hear a 4-Hz pulse as a 240 BPM beat, not a note.